# InstallUtil missing on .Net

Tags: c#, .net

I find it only available for .Net 2.0 but if the user install .Net 3 or later, how do I get InstallUtil.exe to bundle in my setup so that they can install my engine as a Windows Service?

Answer (score 6):

You should continue to use the `InstallUtil.exe` from `\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`.
Thats probably because there has been no change to this utility from 2.0 --> 3.0 --> 3.5.
Hence this does not exist in the 3.0 / 3.5 folders

NOTE: In Windows Server 2008 R2 with SP1 with .NET 3.5 installed, this is pretty much available here `\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`.
In 64 bit Win 2008 R2- the folder path is slightly different but the `installutil.exe` very much available under `\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727`.

[image]

Comment: so I have to install .Net 2.0 on top of .Net 3.5? Could I distribute InstallUtil?

Comment: If you have .NET 3.5, you should have .NET Framework 2.0 components already as it builds on top of it. Refer http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/swiss_dpe_team/WindowsLiveWriter/Migratingfrom.NET1.1to2.03.0and3.5_9C76/image_2.png That might help clarify how it is.

Comment: It doesn't come with InstallUtil and is not in the .Net framework folder. Using W7 64bit.

Comment: That is weird. I have Windows Server 2008 R2 installed with .NET 3.5 SP1 on multiple computers and that all have the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` in them with `InstallUtil.exe` in it

Comment: Note - Atleast in 64 bit windows server 08 R2 - the folder is slightly different i.e `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727` but otherwise - very much still there. No idea about windows 7 though. Never tried it on 7 so cant say for sure

Answer (score 0):

You can find installUtil.exe [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1253920.aspx/1).